# The "Open" and "Save" system dialogs get taller every time I open them

Tags: macos, finder, bug, dialog

I'm using Mac OS 10.10.2, and I believe this problem only occurs with Mac OS X Yosemite.

Here is the dialog box I am talking about:

[image: Dialog box]

I just pressed `Cmd+S` on Ask Different to trigger this dialog.

If I were to close this dialog, and press `Cmd+S` again, this dialog will grow taller, by about 100 pixels, I'd say.

What is causing this? This actually is *really* annoying, as I find myself opening this dialog upwards of 30-40 times a normal work day, causing the dialog to frequently go off the screen, causing inconvenience in saving the files and similar operations.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm not really looking for a fix - I just want this bug to be recorded here, in the event of there being a fix in Mac OS X in the future (only after I upgraded to Yosemite, this started happening).

Comment: Not at a fix, but a workaround that allows resizing the panel once it has grown too big to grab the bottom border: grab a side border, hold the shift key and drag. The panel will resize in both dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common and known bug. Just google "Save Dialog Grows" to see.

Hopefully Apple will fix it with the next point release.

Comment: haha - I was searching by the terms "dialog windows keep getting taller" - couldn't find anything! great to know people have heard about this problem!